# About HTML decimal form input is not recorded when sent from IPhone

Tags: html

I built an HTML page and a form was written as :

```
<form action="process_save_camp.php" method="post">
<input name="desc" type="text"/>
<input name="price" type="text"/>
<input type="submit"/></form>
```

when the form was submitted from chrome browser on a samsumg phone with android OS it was received and recorded correctly in database ,but when it was submitted from chrome browser on IPhone 6 and IPhone 5S as will the input "price" with a decimal value was recorded as : 0 in database not the submitted value was recorded .Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The prob was in submitting a non-english digits ,so when an english digits are submitted every thing goes well .Based on Experiment . thanks.